# Call function from main to a simulation experiment in Anylogic

Tags: function, anylogic

I want to call a function in the Main interface in anylogic  from the compare runs experiment set_up via a button. i.e when my compare runs experiment is running I want that function that is defined in main to run. How is it possible

Answer (score 0):

While there are a number of ways to do that, picking one depends on what you're trying to achieve. Generally, calling `(Main)getEngine().getRoot()` will get the top agent (which is usually **Main** but could be anything, really).

However, with more information regarding what you're trying to achieve a better approach can be suggested.

Comment: What I need is after a number of runs in the compare runs experiment. I want a function to be called from main which will give me  results based on these runs. But this function can be only defined in main.

Comment: Also when I tried (Main)getEngine().getRoot() I am getting null

Comment: where did you put it in the simulation? did you use one of the 'after simulation run' field like in Java Actions [here](https://anylogic.help/anylogic/experiments/compare-runs-experiment.html)?

Comment: "But this function can be only defined in main." But why? Your experiment can gather (and store) any information at the end of every run (and can contain any logic you need). How would a function in Main "give me results based on these runs"? Or are you talking about changing the model behaviour in some way for a run, based on the outcomes of previous runs?

Comment: I am trying to access a library package pycommunicator which I am unable to capture in the compare runs experiment since I want some results after a set of runs. However this library/connector is not being dragged into the experiment . So I want to call it from a function in main.